# Signup and Login within drop down using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am having problem while displaying the login menu in the dropbox because its width is too small.
i have also tried making changes to the bootstrap.css file but nothing works.i just want to increase the size of the drop down box.please tell if there is some other method also.[my fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/amandhapola/h9hwz7pd/)

```
<li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login</a>

              <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="main">

      <h3>Please Log In, or <a href="#">Sign Up</a></h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Facebook</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Google</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login-or">
        <hr class="hr-or">
        <span class="span-or">or</span>
      </div>

      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputUsernameEmail">Username or email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsernameEmail">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <a class="pull-right" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
          <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox pull-right">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            Remember me </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary">
          Log In
        </button>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
          </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/mwi1Ylq39H)

Hope this may useful

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login</a>
                                </li>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="main">

                                            <h3>Please Log In, or <a href="#">Sign Up</a></h3>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Facebook</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Google</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="login-or">
                                                <hr class="hr-or" />
                                                <span class="span-or">or</span>
                                            </div>

                                            <form role="form">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="inputUsernameEmail">Username or email</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsernameEmail">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <a class="pull-right" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                                                    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="checkbox pull-right">
                                                    <label>
                                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                                        Remember me
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary">
                                                    Log In
                                                </button>
                                            </form>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```